How to remove extra margins in text view the most reliable way?
There is an example code:
HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image(systemName: "square.dashed")
            Text("10")
                .font(.system(size: 48))
                .frame(minHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
                .background(.gray)
            Text("10")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .frame(alignment: .top)
                .background(.gray)
        }

The result of this code is quite unexpectable.

There is a margin before the text in a view. Size of the margin depends on a font size — the larger the font, the larger the margin.
How to remove this margin(s) completely?
Tried to use negative paddings:
HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image(systemName: "square.dashed")
            Text("10")
                .font(.system(size: 48))
                .padding(.top, -12) // first magic number
                .frame(minHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
                .background(.gray)
            Text("10")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .padding(.top, -6) // second magic number
                .frame(alignment: .top)
                .background(.gray)
        }

It works, but quite tediously and unreliable: each time I need to adjust the font, I need to adjust this "magic number" thing.
All of these looks quite bizarre. Am I missing something obvious?

See the answer to Aligning SwiftUI text to the baseline and top of another text for an explanation of how a font is sized and Reduce line height to actual characters used in SwiftUI Text element for ways of avoiding the space above and below the digits.

the only way to remove extra paddings on top and bottom of the Text() is to set a correct height of this text. To avoid extra "magic" numbers you could do something like this:
    let size48 = 48.0
    let size24 = 24.0
    
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Image(systemName: "square.dashed")
                Text("10")
                    .font(.system(size: size48))
                    .frame(height: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size48).capHeight)
                    .background(.gray)
                Text("10")
                    .font(.system(size: size24))
                    .frame(height: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size24).capHeight)
                    .frame(alignment: .top)
                    .background(.gray)
            }

Here is used calculated

UIFont.capHeight

value of a desired font size.
And you'll get a correct frames:

